# Arcgis js api dojo.require make many network requests

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arcgis

My question is about `arcgis js api`, I use it in my **Asp.Net** project and it is very good but, there is a problem that I use `dojo.require` and I noticed that it makes about 80-90 network requests to load `js` files.

so I decided to find a solution for this and tried bundling them using asp.net **bundleconfig** class but no luck with this. 
any suggested solutions will be appreciated
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequireJS is mainly used to get dependency files asynchronously. It does this by downloading the individual files and maintains them as modules. That's why you are seen so many requests. The js file request should not be affecting your application performance. Is it? which files have you bundled together?

ESRI API uses dojo, dijit, dgrid etc and some of the request might be for those files. have you bundled all the required file.

You could use the Web Optimizer and create your own bundle file with all the modules you need.

Check this out here.
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_web_optimizer.html#gains